# Downloading an image sometimes times out when requested from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, download

## Background

I have an AWS Lambda function (Node, currently v16) that has been doing its job for many months. It is actively maintained. One of the things it does, is download a number of images of which the URLs are supplied via the payload.

## Problem

Invocations suddenly started failing sporadically. It was clear quickly that some of the requests for downloading the images were timing out. The reason for these timeouts, however, is a mystery.

## Potentially useful details

A list of implementation details, debugging steps I have tried, and other random info that could shed some light on this.

- For each invocation, there are typically between five and fifteen images to be downloaded.
- Most invocations are successful, i.e. all images are downloaded quickly and without problems.
- Invocations fail about 10-15% of the time. In most instances, only a single image fails to download. But I've also seen two or three images time out.
- When retrying invocations, it is always the same image that times out. Sooner or later though, it will suddenly work. Sometimes it works on the second try, sometimes I have to wait a little longer.
- Even when one invocation with a particular payload is failing, others can be successful at the same time.
- When running similar code locally (same payload, same image downloading code) it never fails. So even when the images time out when the request comes from AWS Lambda, it'll still work from my machine.

## Any ideas?

I am open to any suggestions, theories, or debugging ideas.

Comment: Is the Lambda function as a whole timing out? Or just individual threads within the function? It isn't clear from your post what your Lambda timeout value is set to and whether you are reaching that while you are downloading your images.

Comment: Lambda itself is not timing out: the timeout is set to 30s, while the requests for the images are set to take up at most 15s (5s timeout, max 2 retries). So I always get a response from my code, never the `Internal Server Error` you'd get when your code can't complete in time.